# Combo Box Selected ID from value

Tags: vb.net

So i have this sub to load a combo box with some brand names

```
Did it like that and it shows only brand name when i select anything.
```

`Private Sub LoadBrand()
Try
Dim dt As New DataTable()
strConnection = String.Format("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};",
strServer, strDataBase, strUserName, strPassword)

```
        Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        Connection.Open()
        Dim cm As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Codeid,descr FROM EMBONILO_B.DBO.manufacturer GROUP BY Codeid,descr", Connection)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
        dt.Load(dr)
        cmbBrand.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName
        cmbBrand.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
        cmbBrand.DataSource = dt
        Connection.Close()

    Catch oleDbExceptionParameter As OleDbException
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(oleDbExceptionParameter.StackTrace.ToString, Application.ProductName,
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Catch ex As Exception
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, My.Application.Info.Title)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I have combobox which shows up some brands in the Database  there are to columns ID and Brand . What i am looking for is when i select a brand from the combobox to get the ID number from the selected brand as a display value on combobox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Load a DataTable (`[DataTable].Load([Reader])`) with both Columns, set the DisplayMember to the string value and the ValueMember to the numeric value. I.e., don't add stirngs to the Item's collection. After a selection, the `SelectedValue` is set to the corresponding `Codeid`.

Comment: I mean i cant do it with the current combobox ? i have to create a datatable and load the Columns?

Comment: `dim dt as new DataTable() dt.Load(dr) cmbBrand.DisplayMember = "descr" cmbBrand.ValueMember = "Codeid" cmbBrand.DataSource = dt`. Declare Connection and Command with `Using` statements.

Comment: Wait cant i import those lines in the code i mentioned?

Comment: That code is meant to replace `While dr.Read cmbBrand.Items.Add(dr(1)) End While`

Comment: Did it i get system.data.datarowview on the combobox

Comment: You have to set DisplayMember and ValueMember to the actual names of your Columns. It's better if you write: `cmbBrand.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName cmbBrand.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName`

Comment: Did it like that and it shows only brand name when i select anything. Check i edited the post with the code you said.

Comment: As I mentioned in the very first comment, the SelectedValue of your ComboBox holds the ID of the brand selected. Use the SelectedIndexChanged, SelectionChangeCommitted or databindings to show that value in a TextBox or whatever.

Comment: Wait it should not show me in the combo box value (1,2,4,6 ...) and not lets say (Nike,Adidas etc) ?

Comment: Do you want to show the IDs in the ComboBox? Then set the DisplayMember to the Column that holds the IDs.

Comment: Okay found what you mean before it works for me perfect.
Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Just a bit of an extension to Jimi has said, rather than inspecting cmbBrand.SelectedValue, check cmbBrand.EditValue.  It does return an object that needs to be typed, but also means you don't need to hand the Selection changed events

Comment: @Jimi, I would suggest that this question demonstrates why you should write an answer instead of trying to answer questions in comments. If an answer is not clear then you can edit it, rather than a long back and forth like this. I've been guilty of this myself at times but it should generally be avoided.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yep, it got messed up. My bad. I tried to push it, since the original body of the question didn't match the code.  It came out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "hidden" ID value (in your case, the CodeID field) from the ComboBox, you would use the `SelectedValue` property of the ComboBox.

For example:

`Dim MySelectedCodeID As String = cmbBrand.SelectedValue`